# How to evaluate the parameters estimation results from Optim Julia?

Tags: optimization, parameters, julia, inference

I tried to estimate parameters of several ODE systems to fit the same dataset.
When I plot the variables of some models with the estimated parameters, the curves fit quite well with the real dataset.
However, it is just a visual appreciation. I want to justify the selection of the best candidates models (ODE systems) with the optimization results, from the package **Optim** of Julia

To estimate the parameters of a model I used tho following code:

```
prob  = ODEProblem(model,u_0,tspan,params);  
cost_functionEP = build_loss_objective(prob,Tsit5(),L2Loss(sub_t_norm,sub_norm_data),prob_generator = problemEP, maxiters=1000000,verbose = false, save_idxs = [1,4,12] )
result_estimEP  = Optim.optimize(cost_functionEP,lower,upper, params, Fminbox(BFGS()))
```

the output of the optimization, **result_estimEP** is:

```html
 * Status: success

 * Candidate solution
    Final objective value:     2.830272e+05

 * Found with
    Algorithm:     Fminbox with BFGS

 * Convergence measures
    |x - x'|               = 2.17e-19 ≰ 0.0e+00
    |x - x'|/|x'|          = 1.30e-21 ≰ 0.0e+00
    |f(x) - f(x')|         = 0.00e+00 ≤ 0.0e+00
    |f(x) - f(x')|/|f(x')| = 0.00e+00 ≤ 0.0e+00
    |g(x)|                 = 2.12e+07 ≰ 1.0e-08

 * Work counters
    Seconds run:   26  (vs limit Inf)
    Iterations:    6
    f(x) calls:    10034
    ∇f(x) calls:   10034
```

I read the online doc of Optim to understand what does every lines of this output mean but there's not much informations (only for univariate estimation). Could someone who is more familiar with optimization problem than me indicates what these values mean, please?

Answer (score 0):

A few comments that maybe help:

```
 * Status: success # the optimization was successful

 * Candidate solution
    Final objective value:     2.830272e+05 # the loss function value at the end

 * Found with
    Algorithm:     Fminbox with BFGS # the algorithm used

 * Convergence measures
    |x - x'|               = 2.17e-19 ≰ 0.0e+00 # the conditions 
    |x - x'|/|x'|          = 1.30e-21 ≰ 0.0e+00 # that were satisfied
    |f(x) - f(x')|         = 0.00e+00 ≤ 0.0e+00 # or not. These are
    |f(x) - f(x')|/|f(x')| = 0.00e+00 ≤ 0.0e+00 # odd though, see comment.
    |g(x)|                 = 2.12e+07 ≰ 1.0e-08

 * Work counters
    Seconds run:   26  (vs limit Inf)
    Iterations:    6
    f(x) calls:    10034     # number of loss function calls
    ∇f(x) calls:   10034     # number of gradient of loss function calls
```

It seems odd to me that the only condition you satisfied is essentially `f(x) == f(x')`, which suggests that changing `x` to `x'` did not affect the loss function, although the gradient `g(x)` is not zero. Maybe the loss function has problems? Also maybe this is typical of the BFGS algorithm? I'm not sure. However, what's reassuring is that the gradient is not *too* far from satisfying the condition (of being smaller than 1.0e-8), so maybe you have a good minimizer already.

Comment: Very helpful! The odd results is probably due to the parameters I decided to constraint: most of them. In my work, the parameters are classified by biological function. So I constraint parameters per behaviour to highlight their critical importance. This would explain why none of my models entirely solve the loss problem. And yes, the initial minimizer is close to the estimation.